# How to automaticly copy a files from SVN repository

Tags: java, maven, svn

I have a project named HelloWorld. It is a maven java project.

I have got a repository like https://my.repo.com/svn/filesToCopy

What i want to do is:

Automaticly coping 3 files (`a.xsd`, `b.xsd`, `c.xsd`) from SVN repository into my `src/main/resource` directory.

I was trying to add smth like that in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>Coping one file</echo>
                                <copy file="https://my.repo.com/svn/filesToCopy/a.xsd" todir="${basedir}/src/main/resource" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And then just building a project but it isnt working at all.

What is more im wondering if passing a `https` link need a username and password somewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't do such things. Just put those resources into your project and checkit in and that's it.

Comment: @khmarbaise i'm doing this in such way atm. However problem is when there are 300 not 3 files and when these 300 files are often changing. Copying it manualy is pissing me off

Comment: Why do you need to copy them manually just hold them there cause they seemed to belong there. But you might take a look to the [remote-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/) but i have doubt that it is the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this approach? It's from [Maven SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html)

```
<execution>  
  <id>perform-checkout</id>  
  <configuration>  
    <connectionUrl>myUrl</connectionUrl>  
    <checkoutDirectory>myDirectory</checkoutDirectory>  
    <excludes>folder1</excludes>
  </configuration>  
  <phase><!-- some phase --></phase>  
  <goals>  
   <goal>checkout</goal>  
  </goals>  
</execution>
```